# Exception returned when collecting case class from RDD in Spark 2.0

Tags: apache-spark, rdd, case-class

This maybe trivial, but I cannot understand what I'm doing wrong. Looks like collecting a case class from an RDD has some problems.

```
case class Test(val1 :Double, val2 :Double)

val myrdd = sc.makeRDD(Array(Test(1,1),Test(1,1),Test(1,1),Test(1,1)))

myrdd.collect.foreach(x => println(x.val1))
```

returns:

```
stderr]:> failure running last command: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: ClassNotFound with classloader: sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@5d6f64b1
  at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.org$apache$spark$scheduler$DAGScheduler$$failJobAndIndependentStages(DAGScheduler.scala:1450)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$abortStage$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:1438)
  at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$abortStage$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:1437)
  at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray$class.foreach(ResizableArray.scala:59)
  at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.foreach(ArrayBuffer.scala:48)
...
```

If I map the case class to a tuple before collecting everything works fine. Tried to import the case class from a library in the classpath rather than declaring it, same error, no luck. This works fine in a spark shell in local mode.
I'm running Spark 2.0 on a mesos cluster. Any help appreciated.

Comment: I can't reproduce the error with the given information

Comment: Forgot to mention - it works fine in spark shell local mode. Where it breaks is on a cluster running Spark on Mesos. I will edit the question.